# Can you pull the same enemy multiple times with Grasp of Hadar?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, forced-movement, eldritch-invocations

Based on the setting explained by KorvinStarmast [in this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168879/can-a-creature-grasped-by-grasp-of-hadar-move-with-the-warlock), I'd like to know if you can pull someone more than once with Eldritch Blast + Grasp of Hadar if you hit him with multiple blasts (meaning multiple beams or multiple casts of the same cantrip).

The spell description states that you shoot multiple beams as you level up instead of shooting a stronger one, kinda like the Magic Missile spell, which have been ruled by Jeremy Crowford to work a little different from other spells in terms of calculating some effects like the bonus damage from Empowered Evocation [like noted in this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/109678).

I'm aware of the diference in spelling between Grasp of Hadar and Repelling Blast, probably due to 3D combat, but I'm not sure that is really intended to work like that if, for example, you cast it twice in some way.

Comment: Note that you cannot use your hasted action to cast a spell.

Comment: Noted that, I don't really know how to cast two spells in one turn even thought I know you can do it somehow xD

Comment: If you want a way to cast two spells in a turn, the fighter's Action Surge feature is the classic way to do it.

Comment: @Someone_Evil or a Sorcerer's Quickened Spell, although that only works if one of the spells is a cantrip. Or, if you want to cast 3 spells, combine Quickened Spell and Action Surge, and make sure the quickened spell is a cantrip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, you can't (at least not on the same turn or round)

*Grasp of Hadar* explicitly states (emphasis mine):

> **Once on each of your turns** when you hit a creature with your eldritch blast, you can move that creature in a straight line 10 feet closer to you.

If you absolutely want to pull a creature up twice in a round, you can multiclass into Sorcerer and combine *Grasp of Hadar* with a quickened *Thorn Whip* cantrip (which you need to have gained by choosing *Thorn Whip* as a Tome warlock, since neither Warlocks nor Sorcerers have access to the cantrip otherwise).

In my opinion, that's not really worth it, though, since you need at least 3 levels in Sorcerer in order to do this *once* per day, unless you convert your Sorcerer spell slots into Sorcery points for a total of 3+8=11 sorcery points, or 5* per day. Honestly, at that point, you're probably better of going for sorcerer + whatever gives you access to *Thorn Whip*, since that cantrip has no restriction on times/turn, unlike *Grasp of Hadar*.

Another option is multiclassing into Druid, Ranger or Bard in order to get access to *Grasping Vine*, but that's a level 4 spell that has to be anchored to the ground, meaning that you can't pull enemies up and drop them for fall damage unless there's a conventiently placed cliff around on the edge of which you could attach the spell. Either way, multiclassing 7 levels into e.g. Bard (which would suit a Warlock best due to a shared spellcasting ability) for this purpose alone is just absurd (maybe even Abserd).

Comment: Then the problem is on me for not understanding why Grasp of Hadar doesn't work like Repelling Blast (I mean the logic behind that, I get the description is different)

Answer (score 8):

The text of Grasp of Hadar (XGtE, p57) states

> Once on each of your turns when you hit a creature with your Eldritch Blast

So it can't be used multiple times in a turn - hitting with extra beams won't allow more uses.